# Flutter dependency conflict (versions depend on another )

Tags: flutter, dependencies, overriding, version, conflict

I want to add avtar in my App but not able to do this because of dependency conflict/ required version error. I also trying to override dependency but its still not working. also trying this commands.

- Flutter clean
- Flutter pub get

But still not working.

**ERROR:-**

```
  Because no versions of random_avatar match >0.0.7 <0.1.0 and random_avatar 0.0.7 depends on flutter_svg ^1.0.3, random_avatar ^0.0.7 requires flutter_svg ^1.0.3.
    And because flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-alpha.1 depends on flutter_svg >=0.22.0 <1.0.0, random_avatar ^0.0.7 is incompatible with flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-alpha.1.
    So, because seedwill_demo depends on both flutter_html ^2.2.1 and random_avatar ^0.0.7, version solving failed.
    pub get failed (1; So, because seedwill_demo depends on both flutter_html ^2.2.1 and random_avatar ^0.0.7, version solving failed.)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess You working on `Flutter 2`, but `Flutter 3` is released. On `pub`, some libraries are default compatible with `Flutter 3`. In this case, not always newest library is the best option. You must find which library is incompatible. Can You put `pubspec.yaml` to this post? We need TWO version of pubspec.yaml. Previous (which have no error with `pub get`) and new, with this new library. If You show them, I try find the best version of library for You.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems that look alike, and somehow managed to eliminate them by upgrading flutter parts (updating or reinstalling). Have you tried following commands?

```
flutter clean

flutter upgrade

flutter pub upgrade
```

Comment: Still not working. (Same error)

Comment: I would suggest trying to set up a version that is indicated in-between available versions( indicated in terminal ), and maybe there will appear the reason why you get problem